# php divide string into substrings of identical characters

Tags: php, arrays, regex

How can i divide a string into sub-strings consisting of identical characters?

<strike>> For example - "baabbbc" will be ("aa", "bbbb", "c")</strike>

I want them to be stored into an array later -

My code so far is as below -

```
function strSplit($s) {
    $sArr = str_split($s);
    sort($sArr);
    $subStrArr = Array();
    for($i=0; $i<count($sArr); $i++){
        for($j=1; $j<count($Arr); $i++){
            if($sArr[$j] == $sArr[$j-1]){
                $subStrArr[$i][$j-1] = $sArr[$j-1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update:
Apologize for the mistake, I would like the array to be like this,

> "baabbbc" will be ("b", "aa", "bbbb", "c")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy to go with [preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

```
<?php
$string = "baabbbc";
$output_array = preg_split('/(.)(?!\1|$)\K/', $string);

print_r($output_array);
```

https://eval.in/920166

Description:

- `(.)` - match a single character and capture it
- `(?!\1|$)` - look at the next position and match if it's not the same
  as the one we just found nor the end of the string.
- `\K` - keeps the text matched so far out of the overall regex match,
  making this match zero-width.

Comment: I'm sorry, It was my bad i asked question a little off, could you please check the update.

Comment: @KumarAnand  check my edited solution, I have changed it completely based on new update.

Comment: Yes, I just see it. You can also use: `(.)\1*+(?=.)\K`

Answer (score 2):

You may use a simple regular expression:

```
<?php

$string = "baabbbc";

$regex = '~(\w)\1*~';
if (preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches)) {
    $parts = $matches[0];
    print_r($parts);
}
?>
```

This yields

```
Array
(
    [0] => b
    [1] => aa
    [2] => bbb
    [3] => c
)
```

---

The expression

```
(\w)\1*
```

looks for a word character and tries to repeat this as often as possible using a back reference.

Comment: Actually, this is close to what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Without `PREG_SET_ORDER` you don't have to use `array_map`.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Updated, thanks for spotting it. The question has changed in the meantime.